# invalid HTTP response code '404'

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are trying to install:

http://www.activecampaign.com/activespell/

But are getting this JS error:

[CPAINT Error] invalid HTTP response code '404'

It seems the ajax is unable to access something, but not sure what or why, anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means your AJAX is attempting to connect to a resource that is not present at the address where the AJAX is looking.  HTTP 404 literally means the requested resource does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Austin, have worked out what it's calling and what we need to change to fix that. For future reference for others, it's:

<textarea title="spellcheck" accesskey="spell_checker.php" id="spell_checker3" name="comment3" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;" />